# How to convert Pandas Dataframe to csv reader directly in python?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have a csv file on with millions of rows. I used to create a dictionary out the csv file like this

```
 with open('us_db.csv', 'rb') as f:
    data = csv.reader(f)
    for row in data:
       Create Dictionary based on a column
```

Now to filter the rows based on some conditions I use pandas Dataframe as it is super fast in these operations. I load the csv as pandas Dataframe do some filtering. Then I want to continue doing the above. I thought of using pandas **df.iterrows()** or **df.itertuples()** but it is really slow.

Is there a way to convert the pandas dataframe to csv.reader() directly so that I can continue to use the above code. If I use `csv_rows = to_csv()`, it gives a long string. Ofcourse, I can write out a csv and then read from it again. But I want to know if there is a way to skip the extra read and write to a file.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could do something like this..

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import csv

#random dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,4))

buffer = StringIO()  #creating an empty buffer
df.to_csv(buffer)  #filling that buffer
buffer.seek(0) #set to the start of the stream

for row in csv.reader(buffer):
    #do stuff
```

Comment: Thanks. That worked. As I was using python2.7 I had to use BytesIO instead of StringIO() as I had some problems with utf-8 coding.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you apply the Create Dictionary function to the target column?
Something like:

```
df['column_name'] = df['column_name'].apply(Create Dictionary)
```

Comment: I need the whole row to be available inside the function. Apply only send one value at a time. Not one row at a time. Thanks.